# Django view connect to json or config file instead of a db

Tags: json, django-models, django-views, config, ini

So I have a `ListView` to output data from a `DB`, but some data are so diverse it's real pain to use a DB. Is there a way to query a `json/config` file in `Django CBV` instead of a `DB`?